# display:inline resets height and width

Tags: css

I have created example at http://jsfiddle.net/GKnkW/2/

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
 </head>
<body>
      <div class="step">1</div>&nbsp;
      <div class="step">2</div>
      <br/><br/>
      <div class="step1">3</div>&nbsp;
      <div class="step1">4</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.step
{
    height:150px;
    width:150px;    
    background:yellow;
    display:inline;
}

.step1
{
    height:150px;
    width:150px;    
    background:yellow;
}
```

I want to display two divs side by side with their original height and width ( set in css )
as soon as i add display:inline property to css it seems to loose height and width defined earlier. [ check divs with # 1 and #2 which seems to loose height and width setting ]

can some one pin point an error which I seems to be doing or workaround for this weird behavior ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Inline objects don't have heights or widths. Why are you setting them inline to begin with? You probably want to either float them or use `display: inline-block`.

Comment: was not aware of the inline object's behavior. thanks for the enlightenment. changing the display property to inline-block resolves the issue.

Comment: dang!! can't accept answer before 11 minutes..will mark your answer as accepted after that..

Answer (score 15):

Use this:

```
display:inline-block;
```

Comment: inline-block keeps it inline, but allows it to take on block element properties like width and height.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
 </head>
    <body>
      <div class="step-section">
          <div class="step">1</div>
          <div class="step">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="step-section">
          <div class="step">3</div>
          <div class="step">4</div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.step
{
    margin:5px;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;    
    background: yellow;
    float:left;
}

.step-section
{
  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding that I had a similar problem and thought it was a Javascript/Jquery issue. This thread solved for me.

INLINE elements have no width, so you cannot set it via js.

Thanks.

Here's a link to my issue just in case.

[Jquery and Jqueryui: set width not working after using resizable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583899/jquery-and-jqueryui-set-width-not-working-after-using-resizable)