# Jquery and Jqueryui: set width not working after using resizable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, width, resizable

I am writing a grid to show task durations.

I have a set of divs in a display:block and when document is ready I use javascript and jqueryui to:
1) add child divs to the block divs
2) make the child divs draggable and resizable
This works fine.
I would also like to preset the divs width (the task duration), but there is a strange behavior: the divs do not resize after the document is loaded. However as soon as I click on the div border to resize it, the width "pops" to the value I used in the script.

Here is the simplified HTML

```
<div id="gridcontainer">
    <div id="railing_1" class="railing"></div>      
    <div id="railing_2" class="railing"></div> 
</div>
```

And here is the JS on the head of the html doc:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            var displayRange = { "slots": "24", "unit":"h","start":"0" };
            var taskList = {
                "tasks": [
                { "id":"1" , "line":"1", "start":"0","duration":"72" }, 
                { "id":"2" , "line":"1", "start":"73","duration":"48" }, 
                { "id":"3" , "line":"2", "start":"0","duration":"120" }
                ]
            };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function(){
            var railingId;
            var taskId;
            var jTaskId;
            var oNewP;
            var oText;
            var displayRange = { "slots": "24", "unit":"h","start":"0" };
            var taskList = {
                "tasks": [
                { "id":"1" , "line":"1", "start":"0","duration":"72" }, 
                { "id":"2" , "line":"1", "start":"73","duration":"48" }, 
                { "id":"3" , "line":"2", "start":"0","duration":"120" }
                ]
            };
            //get the task list and create/append the children to each line
            for(var i = 0; i<taskList.tasks.length; i++){
                //alert(taskList.tasks[i].duration);
                railingId = "railing_" + taskList.tasks[i].line;
                taskId = "task_" + taskList.tasks[i].id;
                oNewP = document.createElement("div");
                oText = document.createTextNode(taskList.tasks[i].id);
                oNewP.setAttribute("id",taskId);
                oNewP.setAttribute("class","taskbar");
                oNewP.appendChild(oText);
                document.getElementById(railingId).appendChild(oNewP);
                jTaskId = "#" + taskId;
                $(jTaskId)
                    .draggable({ 
                                grid: [ 24, 44 ],
                                containment: "#gridcontainer",
                                axis: "x, y" 
                                })
                    .resizable({
                                grid: [ 24, 0 ],
                                handles: "e, w",
                                containment: "#gridcontainer"
                                });
            }
         });

/*
Here is where I try to preset one of the tasks as an example; I've also
tried using $('#task_2').width("100");
but didn't work
*/

             $('#task_2').css("width","100px");
     </script>
```

I've set a Jsfiddle with the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/tPUpN/

You'll notice that if you try to resize number 2, it pops 100px, then it is able to resize according to the resizable grid (24px)

Of course, I would like task 2 to be preset as 100...

Any ideas?

Apologies for the messy code.

**EDIT**
This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Jquery -- I've tried simply using Javascript width and setAttribute methods, without caring about JQ -- but the result is no resize.
The interesing part about JQ is that when I click to resize, the div pops to the attempted size -- which seems to indicate the document is not "reloading" properly (??) and when I click the div, some magic happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root of the issue found on this Stackoverflow thread:

[display:inline resets height and width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759554/css-displayinline-resets-height-and-width)

INLINE ELEMENTS do not have width, so this is not a Javascript problem. The issue was with the CSS definition. Removed the display: inline instruction and it worked fine.

Thanks for everyone posting bits of wonderful information in SO.