# Display:inline making en element disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this code:

HTML:

```
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#blue{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin-left:50%;
}

#red{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

With this result:

[image]

And so I add `display:inline` to `#blue`, expecting both to be at the same line. Results are strange:

[image]

Why this behaviour? I first thought `#blue` was remaining behind `#red`, but it does not seems to be the case.

Comment: both `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `width` and `height` of a `display: inline` element don't affect it. [See this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5759565/2456263)

Setting both boxes to display inline achieves your desired effect `inline-block`. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vb2y4wf/)