# When window is resized, span element not getting its width

Tags: html, css, wordpress, layout

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

And here's the code:

```
.contact_section .contact_form input[type="text"], .contact_section .contact_form input[type="email"]{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 15px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30.2%;

    display: inline;

    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.contact_section .right_box{
    float: right;
    width: 500px;
}

.contact_form .wpcf7-form-control-wrap:nth-of-type(2){
    margin: 0 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 510px) {
    .contact_section .contact_form input[type="text"], .contact_section .contact_form input[type="email"]{
        margin: 5px auto;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .contact_form .wpcf7-form-control-wrap:nth-of-type(2) {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is that, at normal window size, it looks perfect as shown in the screenshot. But if resize the window(to less than 510px) and back to the full size window, the `email` textbox goes to the next line!

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

What I noticed is that, the parent `<span>` element now doesn't have a width! I have been trying to figure out why its happening, for many hours now. But still no success! :(

Btw, am using `ContactForm7` for the contact form.

---

**EDIT**

SOLVED! I set the `span` elements to `inline-block` as well as set the `30.2%` `width` to them instead of the textboxes. And some margin adjustments fixed the issue! Thank you

Comment: dont you think because it still has margin

Comment: @RaniMorelesRubillos hmm the margins seems to be not the issue. Thank you

Comment: can you give me the link to your actual website or try to inline the span @Vpp Man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS property `display:inline` does not accept widths and heights. Change this to inline-block to solve your issues.

```
.contact_section .contact_form input[type="text"], .contact_section .contact_form input[type="email"]{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 15px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30.2%;

    display: inline-block;

    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Reference: [display:inline resets height and width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759554/displayinline-resets-height-and-width)

Comment: Thank you. I set the `inline-block` as well as the `width` to the `span` elements and it seems to be working now.