# css top and bottom not working on element

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to position an image text overlay just above the image when it is hovered. `top` & `bottom` are not doing the trick.

Here's the code -

```css
.projects {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.desktop-image {
  position: relative;
}

.desktop-image:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  cursor: e-resize;
}

.desktop-image > img {
  width: 700px;
}

.img_description {
  position: absolute;
  top: -13%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .7s, visibility .7s;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.desktop-image > a:hover .img_description {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="projects">
  <div class="desktop-image">
    <a class="desktop-image" href="https://www.stellamccartney.com/gb" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/nintchdbpict000342472436.jpg?strip=all&w=960&quality=100">
      <p class="img_description">
        An event directory that I<br> founded. Development, design &<br> content by me.
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried giving px values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the position and width settings on `.img-description` as shown below. And since you use opacity 0 and 1, you can erase the visibility settings (or vice versa) The text centering is of course optional, as is the white text color (which *does* improve the visibility, though).

```css
.projects {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.desktop-image {
  position: relative;
}

.desktop-image:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  cursor: e-resize;
}

.desktop-image > img {
  width: 700px;
}

.img_description {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 13%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .7s, visibility .7s;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.desktop-image > a:hover .img_description {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects">
  <div class="desktop-image">
    <a class="desktop-image" href="https://www.stellamccartney.com/gb" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/nintchdbpict000342472436.jpg?strip=all&w=960&quality=100">
      <p class="img_description">
        An event directory that I<br> founded. Development, design &<br> content by me.
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

The `a` tag was not taking the full height of the `image` tag because it was set to `display:inline` which does not have height and width, hence I changed it to `display:inline-block` so that it will have block properties too, then the element which had `position:absolute` was getting positioned as usual!

```css
.projects {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.desktop-image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.desktop-image:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  cursor: e-resize;
}

.desktop-image > img {
  width: 700px;
}

.img_description {
  position: absolute;
  top: -13%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .7s, visibility .7s;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.desktop-image > a:hover .img_description {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects">
  <div class="desktop-image">
    <a class="desktop-image" href="https://www.stellamccartney.com/gb" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/nintchdbpict000342472436.jpg?strip=all&w=960&quality=100">
      <p class="img_description">
        An event directory that I<br> founded. Development, design &<br> content by me.
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**References:**

1. [Inline height and width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759554/displayinline-resets-height-and-width)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Naren's answer. Just wanted to show the change when I edited the style in Devtools:

Few more changes to `.image-description` would give you the desired o/p:

- remove `top` property
- set `bottom: 100%`
- set `padding-bottom: 0` if you want image to be strictly aligned with top of image

[image]