# Why doesn't span display height?

Tags: html, css

In the following code, why doesn't span adhere to the height rule:

```
<div style="border:1px black solid">
  inside div
  <span style="height:300px">inside span</span>
</div>
```

http://scratchpad.io/hilarious-shirt-8130

Comment: Inline elements don't have a height

Comment: You're looking for `line-height` with inline elements, or define it as block level amigo.

Answer (score 1):

You gotta put the next style to your span tag

```
display:inline-block;
```

If you wanna see the change put a background to your span

```
background-color: #f00;
```

Comment: Basically you have to use a block element right?

Comment: Yeah, you can check this https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Answer (score 0):

Span is an inline element, which has neither a width nor height of its own. You would need `<span style="height:300px; display:inline-block">` to get a styled height working.

See [display:inline resets height and width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759554/displayinline-resets-height-and-width)